# C#: System.ArgumentException (Out of expected range)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, microsoft-metro

When I try to set the ItemsSource of a GridView with following properties I get the expection `System.ArgumentException("Value does not fall within expected range")`:

Code-Behind

```
OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    ...
    itemGridView.ItemsSource = GetItems(NavigationParameter); // System.ArgumentException
    ...
}
```

GetItems Method

```
private CollectionViewSource GetItems(string key) {
    var items = new List<Item> 
    {
        new Item { Category = "blah", Title = "something" },
        ...
    };
    var itemsByCategories = unsortedItems.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(x => new ItemCategory { Title = x.Key, Items = x.ToList() });

    var _foo = new CollectionViewSource();
    _foo.Source = itemsByCategories.ToList();
    _foo.IsSourceGrouped = true;
    _foo.ItemsPath = new PropertyPath("Items");
    return _foo;
}
```

Why do I get this error?
In XAML, it's works to define a `CollectionViewSource` and set it as a `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Possible duplicate or relation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775294/windows-runtime-gridview-throws-argumentexception-when-setting-itemssource-prope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating and returning a new CollectionViewSource, use an existing CollectionViewSource and update the contents:

```
OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    ...
    GetItems(itemGridView.ItemsSource, NavigationParameter);
    ...
}

private void GetItems(CollectionViewSource source, string key) {
    var items = new List<Item> 
    {
        new Item { Category = "blah", Title = "something" },
        ...
    };
    var itemsByCategories = unsortedItems.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(x => new ItemCategory { Title = x.Key, Items = x.ToList() });

    source.Source = itemsByCategories.ToList();
    source.IsSourceGrouped = true;
    source.ItemsPath = new PropertyPath("Items");
}
```